# How to select data from mysql database by date

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, date

I have an DB Table with a column appointment_date [**type**: **date**], I want select all the data matching with today's date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**MS SQL Server**

Use CURRENT_TIMESTAMP function

`select * from dates where appointment_date = CAST(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP AS DATE);`

**MYsQL**

`select * from dates where appointment_date = cast(now() as date);`

Comment: I have tried above code , but its not working .
Do you have any other suggestions.

Comment: What Db are u using?